# Realistic material for Moon landscape

Tags: materials, node-editor, shaders, lighting, normals

I'm trying to create a realistic material for my moon landscape [image: real image] [image: viewport Blender][image]The real image has a lot more details, but I'm interested in the white areas exposed to sunlight. I would like this to be a property of the material so that I can use it with different illuminations. How can I overexpose only the areas with normals close to the directions of the light rays?

Comment: You should be able to find real images with corresponding height maps online. NASA's website probably has loads of material on this in high resolution. So you get albedo and displacement maps and that's pretty much it. You can probably get away with a diffuse shader. The misunderstanding about lighting being a property of material will probably have to go though. Not really sure what you could possibly be struggling with here. Maybe providing the context would help.

Comment: The white areas around craters are recently exposed material which hasn't darken yet. Some craters are young (bright), some are older (dark). If you want to go for a realistic look, it would be easier to use NASA color maps and height maps as Martynas Žiemys said. Otherwise, you'd have to build a somewhat complex shader to reproduce these colors. Depends on your needs.

Comment: I have the height maps and the real images. The issue is that those images are taken at precise illumination conditions. I was wondering if it was possible to have an effect similar to the real images (the white areas exposed to the sunlight) with a dynamic illumination.

Comment: Color maps aren't "at precise illumination conditions", they represent the color with a perfectly homogenous lighting. Just the color of the surface https://svs.gsfc.nasa.gov/4720. If you are using photos with a specific lighting, you're basically screwed.

Comment: Indeed, it is what I'm using. I want to use high-resolution images for my model. Those are available only with the LROC's NAC (narrow-angle camera). Unfortunately, I don't think they have done many passages in the same areas; therefore, the images are in a specific illumination condition. I tried to use the WAC color map for the whole moon, but the details are not great for areas that are only a few km wide.